# jQuery UI Datepicker showing incorrect week number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

When using the jQuery UI Datepicker and starting the week on a Sunday, the week numbers are incorrect. For example, 3rd Jan 2016 should be week 1 as all of the dates (3rd to 9th) are in the same year. But as you can see in the screenshot below, the UI shows it as week 53.

[image]

Here is the code to render the datepicker:

```
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 0
});
```

So nothing special, other than showing the week numbers and starting the week on Sunday instead of Monday (as per default).

Here is a fiddle of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/vLqabmmz/

Comment: try adding +1 to your firstDay. reference link : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#show-week

Comment: @ameenulla0007 that would make the week start on Monday then!

Comment: The fact that setting `firstDay: 1` fixes the problem would seem to indicate  a bug in the week number calculation. You can provide your own implementation of it according to http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showWeek, by providing a function to `calculateWeek`.

Comment: yup right, did you refer the link!!, jQuery UI example shows you the same kind of result, seems like, there is a bug in the new UI library with datepicker. week starting from no. 53

Comment: according to iso8601 (jquery uses this), 3rd is week 53 and 4 .. is week 1 so still wrong you should report this to the team

Comment: @vtz So is iso8601 itself incorrect, or the jquery implementation of iso8601 incorrect?

Comment: something is wrong with jquery, there different standards from iso8601 but yes the probllem is in the library and this should be reported in order fro the devs to help, this is quite an issue

Comment: Bug submitted here: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14907#ticket

Comment: this still hasn't been fixed yet? does anyone have any possible solutions? I must use Sunday as the first day (firstDay: 0) and this is holding me back...grrr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that this seems like a bug in jQuery UI. I'm posting the possible answer being the reporting of this as a bug to the jQuery UI team here: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14907#ticket

Comment: you can check my answer, this is a layout issue and you can update the ticket if you agree of course

Answer (score 2):

As seen from documentation for `calculateWeek` [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-calculateWeek):

> This function uses the ISO 8601 definition of a week: weeks start on a Monday and the first week of the year contains January 4.

So comments are right qualifying this as a bug. While this is not resolved yet, you can overcome this easily by setting `firstDay` to 1 like this:

```
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1
});
```

Week number would be correct, it is easier than rewrite `calculateWeek`, **only difference is that week will start on Monday instead on Sunday**. Note that [default behavior sets `firstDay` to 0.](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-firstDay)

Answer (score 1):

i checked further and iso8601Week() method of jqueryUI is working fine, the problem is in its representation (the layout).

If you extract the value of the week you can see that the standard is followed and is fine. 3-rd is week 53 and after that 4 ... 7 (which is the first Thursday of the year and this is the week number 1). You can check with the code below.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).val("'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yeah iso8601 is working fine. The issue is that iso8601 shouldn't be used if the week starts on another day other than Monday as it messes up the week numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a display of the jQuery calendar for the first week of 2017 - fully contained in a new year.
Yet, the week number is shown as 52 of year 2016 (wtf).
[image]

To me it looks like a bug to be corrected, otherwise there is no reason to display the week number.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date:

The first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year (and, hence, always contains 4 January).

Comment: Yes, but it also says, "Weeks start with Monday". In the example given, Sunday the 3rd truly should be week 53 but Monday the 4th should be week 1. By setting the start of the week to be Sunday instead of Monday as the OP said, there's no current way of displaying both week 53 (for the 3rd) and week 1 (for the 4th) in the same row.

Comment: Take a look at first week of 2017 - which starts on Sunday Jan 1 and contains first Thursday on Jan 5th. jQuery incorrectly marked it as 52 week instead 1st week of 2017 .

Answer (score 0):

You should update locale:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    week: {
        dow: 1,
        doy: 1
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1
});
```

start day on monday, then it gets the week number of the monday and not the sunday, that should fix your weeks.

Comment: Someone else already posted this same answer 7 years ago with more details and links to the documentation.